# pyautogui.pixel(x,y) starts lagging in a while loop

Tags: python, pyautogui

I want to check when a pixel on the screen is changing and then put a keyboard event when the pixel is changing colors. But after about 2-4 min the computer slows down when `pyautogui.pixel()` have been called multiple times.

Here is my code

```
import pyautogui

OldC1 = None

while True:
   NewC1 = pyautogui.pixel(750, 550)

   if NewC1 != OldC1:
      pyautogui.press('up')

   OldC1 = NewC1;
```

Is there a way to get around the lag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered similar issues, my way of circumventing that problem was to use PIL's functions directly, instead of pyautogui's wrapper functions:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

pixelRGB = ImageGrab.grab().getpixel((x, y))
```

Using this function did not slow down my pc.

Comment: he's using this function in an infinite loop that's slowing his pc, not specifically the module through which he achieves the pixel values.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but my test results showed differently. Somehow, and I don't know why, running pyautogui.pixel() in and infinite loop slows down my PC significantly, especially towards the 10.000 call limit, but ImageGrab.grab() doesnt at all. I've left it running well beyond 50k calls and there was no performance difference from when I started the test.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not that much with the function that you are using to get the values, but from the infinite loop that is running continuously at all times.

If the time precision is not required, then i would recommend putting a bottleneck on the loop cycles, via a function similar to `sleep()`

**TRY:**

```py
from PIL import ImageGrab
import time

OldC1 = (0, 0, 0)

while True:

   time.sleep(.3)
   NewC1 = ImageGrab.grab().getpixel((750, 550))

   if NewC1 != OldC1:
      pyautogui.press('up')

   OldC1 = NewC1
```

The `time.sleep(2)` will reduce the frequency of iterations, and in turn will result into a lot better performance in the long run.

**EDIT:**

Instead of using `pyautogui`'s pixel function to get a specific pixel's RGB values, I rather used `getpixel()` from `PIL` (Python Imaging Library) module, the reason is because `pyautogui.pixel()` function is just a wrapper of `ImageGrab.grab().getpixel()`, and since we are striving for performance, we should instead used `getpixel()` directly, for a little performance boost.

**PS:**

`pyautogui.pixel()` has a limit to total pixel lookups which is somewhere around 10,000. [Read This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50435207/pyautogui-pixelmatchescolor-returns-impossible-value-with-a-10-000-usage-limi/56203965#56203965). This may lead to incorrect results, if lookup value exceed 10,000, `PIL`'s `getpixel()` doesn't have this threshold value.