# Pyautogui/OSError in Python

Tags: python, pyautogui, oserror

I have recently started working with python, and am fairly new to the subject. Currently, I am working on a project that will simulate keyboard presses depending on specific pixel values on the screen. Basically, if "such pixel" is colored "such color", then click/press. However, my code has a bug. Sometimes, it runs perfectly fine, but then randomly stops running. Other times, it doesn't run at all. In both cases, an error appears (below code). Here is my current code:

```
import random
import time

import keyboard
import pyautogui
import win32api
import win32con
from pyautogui import *
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller


simulate = Controller()


def click(x, y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0)


def jump():
    simulate.press(Key.up)
    simulate.release(Key.up)
    click(650, 540)
    print("Jumped!")


def duck():
    simulate.press(Key.down)
    simulate.release(Key.down)
    print("Ducked!")


def restart():
    click(950, 500)


def switch():
    simulate.press(Key.alt)
    simulate.press(Key.tab)
    simulate.release(Key.alt)
    simulate.release(Key.tab)


def play():
    while not keyboard.is_pressed('a'):
        if pyautogui.pixel(660, 540)[0] != 247:
            jump()

        if pyautogui.pixel(950, 500)[0] == 83:
            restart()


switch()
play()
switch()
```

And here is the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:...\main.py", line 59, in <module>
    play()
  File "C:...\main.py", line 51, in play
    if pyautogui.pixel(660, 540)[0] != 247:
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 584, in pixel
    return (r, g, b)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 124, in __exit__
    next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 113, in __win32_openDC
    raise WindowsError("windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0")
OSError: windll.user32.ReleaseDC failed : return 0

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why does this code only work sometimes, and then randomly stop? Is it an issue with downloads or imports, or something else? If you could help, that would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59146513/pyautogui-and-pyscreeze-crash-with-windll-user32-releasedc-failed

Comment: I looked at what you shared, but it doesn't work for me. I am trying to get a specific pixel's value from my screen, not an image. Is there any other way to do so?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with pyautogui, so I'm going to refer to other posts. What about this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55920549/pyautogui-pixelx-y-starts-lagging-in-a-while-loop I tested it and it returned the pixel value for a specific pixel on my screen, without depending on pyautogui and using PIL directly.

Comment: I tried using this, but it says there Is no module named "PIL". Could it be that PIL is not supported in Python 3.9? What version were you able to use it on?

Comment: My version is Python 3.9.2, in an anaconda installation, under Windows 10. Did you run `pip install pillow`?

Comment: I just tried the other solution from that link, it worked! Changing my python version to 3.7 made sure the error didn't appear again. Thank you!

Comment: It's a bug. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67988905/495990